# Validate birthday in integer type

Tags: cakephp

This is the validation in my InfoModel. **I want to validate birthday** but the **"birthday" field is int(8)** in DB. Unluckily I don't have permission to modify MySQL DB table. Now how to validate it?

Example of birthday: 19800101

I tried this but I can't think a solution to convert birthday to string.

```
var $validate = array(
    'job_id'        => array( 'rule' => 'notEmpty'              , 'message' => 'Text here' ),
    'sex_id'        => array( 'rule' => 'notEmpty'              , 'message' => 'Text here' ),
    'first_name'    => array( 'rule' => array( 'between', 1, 5 )    , 'message' => 'Text here' ),
    'last_name'     => array( 'rule' => array( 'between', 1, 5 )    , 'message' => '' ),
    //'birthday'        => array( 'rule' => 'some regex', 'message' => 'Text here' )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that only with a regular expression you can not validate a date, including leap years and total days of a month.

You can add your own validation method. Try this:

```
public $validate = array(
        'birthday' => array(
            'rule' => 'validateBirthday',
            'message' => 'Wrong date of birthday'
        )
);

public function validateBirthday($check) {
    $value = array_values($check);
    $value = $value[0];

    if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', $value, $matches)) {
        return checkdate($matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1]);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

More information:

- [Data Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods)
- [checkdate()](http://php.net/checkdate)

Comment: Yes, it works. I use `preg_match()` to separate day, month and year. Simply include the function `validateBirthday` in your model and change `$validate` variable.